# If a value is x in an input box display a message using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an input box (spinner)

```
div id="site_content">
        <div id="content">
            <h:body>


                <h:form> 
                    <p:spinner id="minutes" min="0" max="1000" value="#{printerSettings.t}"  size ="1">
                        <p:ajax update="NewTime"/>
                    </p:spinner>
                    <p:commandButton  type="submit" action="#{email.mail(printerSettings.t, printerSettings.p, printerSettings.paperSize, printerSettings.duplex, printerSettings.orienation, printerSettings.printer)}" onclick="Thankyou()" value="Print" />


                </h:form>
            </h:body>
        </div>
    </div>
```

on submit, i wonder if it would be possible, if a user had typed in 1001 to bring up an error message, there is validation behind this, but i want to show the user this

it can be done using either javascript or query, but i have no idea where to start, completely new to these languages,

does any one have any examples / links on how to achieve this ?

Comment: So what's the actual HTML that's generated by whatever that is?

Comment: Have you tried $('#minutes').val()?

Comment: _"completely new to these languages"_ - I guess somebody has to point out that jQuery is not a language. JavaScript is a language, but jQuery is a library of JavaScript functions.

Comment: Its xhtml i am building a jsf web application, will post more code in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var minuteVal = $('#minutes').val();
    if(minuteVal > 1000 || minuteVal < 0) {
        alert(minuteVal);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however for the symbol < i get the error `Fatal error the content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup`

Comment: are you putting it in a <script type="text/javascript"> </script> set of tags?  That error sounds like it was pasted in the markup section without a script tag...?

Comment: Also, try a CDATA section in your XML, if necessary - that will allow <, >, &, and other XML entities in the code

Comment: Yes i have put the code in the correct tags, and since it is a xhtml / JSF application i do not have any XML

Comment: Ok, have found a way around it, however the script is displaying undefined when i try to display 'minuteVal'

Comment: you could try "var minuteVal = $('#minutes').text();" as well - just replace val() with text()